# accessing json elements from python by url

Tags: python, arrays, json, key

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
{
    "Search":[
        {"Title":"The Maze Runner",
        "Year":"2014",
        "imdbID":"tt1790864",
        "Type":"movie",
        "Poster":"}
    ],
    "totalResults":"97",
    "Response":"True"
}
```

I want to print the value `totalResults` at the end of file.
here is my code:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError
import json

url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=maze' 

response = urlopen(url)
data = json.load(response)   
print data['Search'][0]['totalResults']
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: `data['totalResults']`

Comment: may thanks i',m idiot :)

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
print data['totalResults']
```

If you look closely 'totalResults' is not inside 'Search'

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is, probably. (in json data it's missing a quote? `"poster":""`)

```
print ('totalResults:'+data['totalResults'])
```

For exemple, a simple solution:

```
data={"Search":[{"Title":"The Maze Runner","Year":"2014","imdbID":"tt1790864","Type":"movie","Poster":""}], "totalResults":[{"quantity":"97"}],"Response":"True"}

data_string = json.dumps(data)
decoded = json.loads(data_string)

print ("There are "+str(decoded["totalResults"][0]["quantity"])+" results.")
```